# Do I need a transit visa for overnight transit in Chengdu China with Nepalese passport?

Tags: visas, transit, china, nepali-citizens

I have 4 hours and 30 minutes in Chengdu China which goes from the 22nd to the 23rd. Do to I need a transit visa as I am a Nepalese passport

Flight from Kathmandu to Chengdu: 22 MAR 1545 to 2100
Flight from Chengdu to Melbourne: 23 MAR 0130 to 1520

Answer (score 1):

When inputting your info into the [IATA Travel Centre tool](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) it spits out the following:

Document: Nepal Passport

Itinerary: Kathmandu-Chengdu 22 MAR 1545-2100 -> Chengdu-Melbourne: 23 MAR 0130-1520

[image: ChinaTWOV]

So it seems that TWOV is allowed as long as it happens within 24h (not 1 calendar day).